# initialization with serialize/deserialize ember.js

Tags: routes, ember.js

I'm using the new `Router` without ember-data so I have to implement my own `serialize`/`deserialize` for dynamic url segments.

I have an `ArrayController` which is populated with data within `Application#ready`.

For simplicities sake, lets say I have 2 routes: `item > '/item/:item_id'` & `items > '/items'`.

The deserialize method in the `item` route looks something along the lines of this

```
 deserialze: function(router, params){ 
     return router.get('myController')
                  .findProperty('id', params['item_id']);
 }
```

If I initialize my app on the `items` route and navigate to the `item` route for a specific item via an `{{action}}` everything works fine. Also, after this point I can manually change the url to specific `id`'s without a problem.

However, if I try to start my app in the `item` route (ie `/item/2`), `deserialize` returns undefined. I'm assuming this is because `Application#ready` hasn't finished populating the controller.

How do I get around this?

**Edit:** I think [this](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/#toc_asynchrony) answers my question. Use ember-data.

> ## ASYNCHRONY
>
> One final point: you might be asking yourself how this system can work if the app has not yet loaded Post 1 > by the time `App.Post.find(1)` is called.
>
> The reason this works is that `ember-data` always returns an object immediately, even if it needs to kick off a query. That object starts off with an empty `data` hash. When the server returns the data, ember-data updates the object's `data`, which also triggers bindings on all defined attributes (properties defined using `DS.attr`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to correct your initialization problem, but you definitely don't have to use `ember-data` if you don't want to.

Personnaly, I have :

- overridden the `deserialize` method for all `Ember.Route`,
- defined an `App.ModelFetcher` class that has class methods :

  - `find(id, doneRequestCallback, failRequestCallback)`
  - `all(doneRequestCallback, failRequestCallback)`
- call `App.ModelFetcher.find(id, function() {}, function() {})` directly in the `deserialize`

These two methods, as `ember-data` does, returns respectively an empty `App.Model` object, and an empty array. When the request is done, these objects are inflated with request values.

There could be better solution, but it works fine for me, and does not look so bad.

You could also, instead of overriding the `deserialize` method, just define the classic `App.Model.find(id)` function (which returns an empty `App.Model` instance), and then set a state to your object, like `ember-data` does (see http://goo.gl/3otkt).

The method will automatically be called by ember if the dynamic segment has the format `model_id` (see http://goo.gl/y86KE).

Anyway, I could be wrong, but I don't like the fact you're trying to get the object in your controller, but I have no other solution than those describe above.